# How do I get kotlin-logging (MicroUtils) to print to subclass name instead of abstract class name?

Tags: kotlin, logging, slf4j, kotlin-logging

I'm using kotlin-logging (https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging), I want my logger to print to subclass name instead of abstract class name. Example I have these class

```
// in A.kt file:

import mu.KotlinLogging

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

abstract class A<T> {
    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}



fun main() {
    val b: A<String> = B()
    b.someMethod("123")
}




// in B.kt file

import mu.KotlinLogging

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

class B : A<String>() {
}
```

It prints: **[main] INFO A - testing**

But I want it to print: **[main] INFO B - testing**  (where B is the subclass name)

Comment: It is usually a better practice to print the abstract class because logger should indicate the place the log was printed clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to send the logger to the abstract class.

```
// in A.kt file:

import mu.KotlinLogging

abstract class A<T>(private val logger: KLogger) {
    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}



fun main() {
    val b: A<String> = B()
    b.someMethod("123")
}




// in B.kt file

import mu.KotlinLogging

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

class B : A<String>(logger) {
}
```

**Result:** `[main] INFO B - testing`

Answer (score 3):

If the logger were inside of your abstract Class A, you could use the logger(name: String) method instead of the logger(func: () -> Unit) method like so:

```
// in A.kt file

import mu.KotlinLogging

abstract class A<T> {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger("${this::class.java.name}")

    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val b: A<String> = B()
    b.someMethod("123")
}

// in B.kt file

class B : A<String>() {
}
```

So that any class that extends A would be logged according to its own class name.

Result: `INFO B - testing`

Why? 
KotlinLogging has two methods, one using the `logger(name: String)` and one using `logger(func: () -> Unit)` found here:
https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/src/jvmMain/kotlin/mu/KotlinLogging.kt#L14-L16

The `logger(func: () -> Unit)` calls the `logger(name: String)` internally using the class name of the function:
https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/src/jvmMain/kotlin/mu/internal/KLoggerFactory.kt#L29-L30

In your case, the function call in A.kt is `private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}` is from inside A.kt, never outside that file, so it will always be from A.
so it finds `A` in this name resolver:
https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/src/jvmMain/kotlin/mu/internal/KLoggerNameResolver.kt#L15-L23

If we use this code here:

```
import mu.KotlinLogging

private val funcJavaClass: String = {}.javaClass.name

abstract class A<T> {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger("${this::class.java.name}")

    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("$funcJavaClass")
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}
```

the result is `AKt$funcJavaClass$1` so when we slice the name here:
https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/blob/master/src/jvmMain/kotlin/mu/internal/KLoggerNameResolver.kt#L18
the result is simply `A`

It's also worth noting that the original example uses `A` because the file name is A, not because of the class.

```
// in R.kt

import mu.KotlinLogging

private val funcJavaClass: String = {}.javaClass.name

abstract class A<T> {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger("${this::class.java.name}")

    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("$funcJavaClass")
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}
```

result: `RKt$funcJavaClass$1`

whereas if the function is called from inside the class

```
// in R.kt

import mu.KotlinLogging

abstract class A<T> {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger("${this::class.java.name}")
    private val funcJavaClass: String = {}.javaClass.name

    fun someMethod(item: T?) {
        logger.info("$funcJavaClass")
        logger.info("testing")
    }
}
```

result: `A$funcJavaClass$1`